# Flutter StatefulWidget has no widget property

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StatefulWidget that sets a backend for Android:

```
class ToeKickSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  ToeKickSettings({
    Key key,
    this.backend
  }) : super(key: key);
  final AndroidBackend backend;
  @override
  _ToeKickSettingsState createState() => _ToeKickSettingsState();
}

class _ToeKickSettingsState extends State<ToeKickSettings> {
  double default_bottom_spacing = 5;
  List<Widget> listChildren = [];

  _ToeKickSettingsState() {
    generateListsFromSoundPacks().then((val) => setState(() {
      listChildren = val;
    }));
  }

  Future<List<Widget>> generateListsFromSoundPacks() async {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    List<String> soundPacks = await widget.backend.common.listSoundPacks();
    //...
  }
 }
```

I access the backend on the state part of the `StatefulWidget` by doing `await widget.backend.common.listSoundPacks();`

I'm getting this error:

```
E/flutter (23645): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'backend' was called on null.
E/flutter (23645): Receiver: null
E/flutter (23645): Tried calling: backend
E/flutter (23645): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (23645): #1      _ToeKickSettingsState.generateListsFromSoundPacks (package:flutter_app/toe_kick.dart:131:44)
```

Which suggests that there's no `widget` property when `generateListsFromSoundPacks` is called. I suspect it has to do with how early I call `_ToeKickSettingsState()`, from `_ToeKickSettingsState createState() => _ToeKickSettingsState();`. It's possible that the `wodget` property hasn't been setted yet.

What can I do?

Comment: try co call ```generateListsFromSoundPacks``` in ```initState``` life cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `widget` in the `State class`'s constructor, move the code in constructor to `initState`.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    generateListsFromSoundPacks().then((val) => setState(() {
      listChildren = val;
    }));
  }
```